# Modifying Solana Smart Contract

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, solana, nft

I’m getting my feet wet with Solana smart contracts.

Basically, I used Ambition (the NFT service) to create a contract and ultimately (unfortunately) I deployed the contract on the main with the wrong metadata base URI.

I need to either:

A) make a live edit to the contract to generate mints with the new/correct Base URI
B) have a whole new contract done and potentially published with the same token id

It’s a side project, and I’m in about $80 so far in gas fees, setup and stuff, so if I can salvage the existing contract I want to do so. Whether that’s through Solidity, or some other means. Any guidance would be very helpful.

Sorry if my question is a foolish one! :-)

Comment: Are you sure this is Solana? ERC 721 is Ethereum, Solana doesn't cost $80 in gas fees, and you can't use solidity for NFTs today on Solana

Comment: I’m sure it’s Solana. The gas was about $42 to deploy the contract, but I incurred other fees for getting my collection uploaded, etc.

Comment: I understand that the point is that you can't change the contract - hence it's a contract. I might be wrong. I'm not an expert, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So the contract is/was upgradable, so a modification to a live smart contract on the Solana Mainnet is possible. Ultimately, I ended up
Withdrawing my contract (which returned my SOL rent funds) and starting over.